# How to manage memory with ARC mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm creating an ios application and I have enabled the ARC mode.
I'm loading 24 instances to a ScrollView, but only three views will be displayed at a given time. So, I will remove the other unwanted instances which are already loaded in to the memory

```
if((NSNull *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] != [NSNull null]) {
    [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:[NSNull null]];
    [content3.view removeFromSuperview];
    //remove third content page
    [content3 viewDidUnload];
    //set nil to instance to memory management
    content3 = nil;

    NSLog(@"Content 3 removed");
}
```

But when I check with the profiler, the memory won't be released, it just increases automatically.

Can anyone give me some tips regarding this issue?

Thanks

Comment: that manual call to `removeFromSuperview` and `viewDidLoad` looks nasty.

Comment: The `viewDidUnload` call is not necessary, nor it is advised to call it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a lot of issues in your code:

1. One important issue is, you are calling the delegate method `viewDidUnload`. Never try to do such things, else you'll face weird behaviours from your app.
2. If you need to remove an object from memory, just set it to nil.
3. I think Your if condition never work, Why are you type casting it to NSNull ?

Check with this code:

```
if([viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] != [NSNull null])
{
    [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:[NSNull null]];
    [content3.view removeFromSuperview];
    content3 = nil;
    NSLog(@"Content 3 removed");
}
```

Comment: Casting of the pointer would not cause a difference in the operation, since pointer comparison always looks at the address anyway, but it is not needed since `objectAtIndex:` returns type id.

Comment: hi. thanks for the reply . i changed my if  condition according to ur source but. still when i checked with the allocation. thr is no decrees on memory